# Foundation Button After Click

Tags: css, button, zurb-foundation

I am using the Foundation Framework in my React app. I have a couple buttons and after being clicked it leaves the buttons with a blue background.

How do I change this?

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/pb4759jh68/a4kowth5/5/

HTML

```
<button class="button">
Click Me
</button>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  background-color:red;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like foundation has a CSS class that is active during the button's `Focus` state.

You can override this with using the following CSS class:

```
.button:focus {
     background-color: green;
}
```

[image]